# Exception class name 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError'

Tags: java, android, apache-poi

My application works to store data stored in an external excel file. When I uploaded it to the Play Store and downloaded it to my device, I tested the application and found a problem when I select an excel file for the application to store. The application does not respond and closes the application while I installed
The application was transferred to my phone via USB from the Android Studio program and I found it working properly

Please help my brothers.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoM5U.jpg)

Comment: It may be some packaging issue. You can find same question below
https://stackoverflow.com/q/34413/14226243

Comment: At least one would need the full log message to get **which** class definition was not found.